# Ошибка в локализации тревоги

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если на вопрос оставить тревогу, и после попытаться снова отправить тревогу, открывается форма выбора пунктов, несколько полей неактивные (всё как и должно быть) и красным подписано:

> Вы уже использовали тревогу с реком**А**ндацией к закрытию

[image: Снимок.jpg]

Comment: Спасибо! Поправил!